# Livepatch keeps failing

Tags: canonical-livepatch

Livepatch seems to be having internal errors ALL THE TIME, mostly when there’s an update but almost randomly now, how do I make it just work without disabling it? Is there something that won’t just last 5 minutes as solution?
It’s the same “Livepatch has experienced an internal error” message with a link to their website, which doesn’t help

Comment: Adding some details to your question such as the exact errors you are receiving will greatly increase your odds of getting help.

Comment: and please [edit] your question with Ubuntu version details...